# Does numpy.all_close check for shape for the array like elements being compared

Tags: python, numpy

Its not clear from the documentation whether numpy.all_close check for shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `allclose` is:

```
def allclose(a, b, rtol=1.e-5, atol=1.e-8):
    # doc...
    x = array(a, copy=False, ndmin=1)
    y = array(b, copy=False, ndmin=1)
    # special handling of 'inf'...
    with errstate(invalid='ignore'):
        r = all(less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y)))

    return r
```

Notice that it insures the inputs are arrays (with at least 1 dim).  That's why it works with your nested lists.

Secondly the core action is `x-y`.  It checks that the absolute difference for all terms is small.  So if it can broadcast the arrays to do the math, it can compare the arrays.  It's the subtraction that issues a broadcasting `ValueError`.